# giving border radius to ant-design card in react

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

so, I am having ant-design card that needs a border radius, but if I add Inline CSS, it still not working, I also tried

And here is the follow code:

`<Card style = {{width: 300, margin: "20px", borderRadius: "20px"}} actions = {[<h4 style = {{ paddingTop: "6px"}} key="Name">Table Name </h4>,]}></Card>`

Is there any way I can control the border radius of this card?

Comment: Adding inline css should work fine - https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-card-antd-4-16-13-forked-0tki1?file=/index.js:268-288

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `overflow:hidden` with `borderRadius` to the card style will fix the issue of the actions container's corners not being round.

```
<Card
  style={{
    width: 300,
    margin: "20px",
    borderRadius: "20px",
    overflow: "hidden"
  }}
  actions={[
    <h4 style={{ paddingTop: "6px" }} key="Name">
      Table Name{" "}
    </h4>
  ]}
>
  <p>Card content</p>
  <p>Card content</p>
  <p>Card content</p>
</Card>
```

[image: Edit antd reproduction template (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

<Card style={{ width: 300, margin: "20px", borderRadius: "20px", overflow: "hidden" }} actions={[ <h4 style={{ paddingTop: "6px" }} key="Name"> Table Name{" "}  ]} >

Card content

Card content

Card content

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `px` within a style object you don't need to assign a unit measurement.

Just change `borderRadius: "20px"` to `borderRadius: 20` - https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-card-antd-4-16-13-forked-jl9fv?file=/index.js

Would be good if ant-design had this in their API but it looks like they leave that up to you.

Comment: yes, I tried that too. but I was having the same results